# Criterion 2 electronic ignition 3 rd burner not lighting

Tags: heating, furnace

On my furnace all sequences run thru fine but occasionally the first burner ignites the second takes off but the third doesn’t what could this be

Comment: Could be be a few things, from dirt/soot to bad electronics.  Probably a good idea to have someone who knows come and check it out.  Not something you want to keep happening.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does each burner have its own igniter?  What's the layout?  What have you done in the way of inspecting and diagnosing?  Can you include pictures?

Answer (score 1):

The problem when burners are not all lighting is usually rust scale and or soot. Soot is more common with fuel oil and rust scale is more common with propane and natural gas.

I usually shut off the gas and igniter if electronic that little spark actually bites a little if you have it in your hand and it starts trying to light.

The burners usually lift out in the back and then slip off the manifold.
I usually use a wire brush and clean the burner noting to clean the small orifices that may be plugged, when I do this I clean all the burners.
All but one or 2 have had a single igniter , if multiple points one could have failed and this can be seen by watching and looking for the spark, in some cases two small of a spark won’t light so slightly increasing the gap, not two much because two large a gap ant the voltage won’t jump to create a spark.
Cleaning has been a 100% fix for me , after cleaning sometimes a air mixture adjustment is needed for the most efficient burn, there are many videos on line giving examples of a nice blue flame with a orange tip, to all orange by just adjusting the air being sucked into the burner.
Note in my area there are tiny spiders that love the air intakes and can cause all kinds of trouble with the air mixture, they are more common outside on propane/gas grills but I have found them many times on open combustion gas fired furnaces (usually noticed the first of the heating season).